# How to convert millisecond into the correspond time?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I'm trying to convert a dynamic value `milliseconds` like this:

> 1800000

into the correspond time, should be `30` minutes.
This is my code:

```
var time = new Date(milliseconds);
console.log("time => " , time);
var m = time.getMinutes();          
console.log("m => ", m);
```

> time =>  Thu Jan 01 1970 08:00:00 GMT+0100 (ora solare Europa occidentale)
>   
>   m =>  30

This is correct but if I try with this milliseconds value => `25200000`

m return this => `0`

There's a correct way to return the correspond minutes?

Answer (score 3):

`Date()` objects are overkill here.  It's just division:

```
var minutes = milliseconds / (1000 * 60);
```

Or, if you don't want any fractional minutes,

```
var minutes = Math.floor(milliseconds / (1000 * 60));
```

In your example, you're turning the milliseconds into a date -- the date/time `milliseconds` ms past 1/1/1970.  After an hour has passed, `getMinutes()` will return `0` again, as the *hours* have incremented, etc.

Comment: Good solution, thanks. I've just one question: In particular cause I got -100 minutes there's a way to check if in the returned value there's a minus before the number or check if the minutes is correct?

Comment: `if (milliseconds < 0)...` ?

Answer (score 0):

You need this approach:

```
var milliseconds = 1800000;
var minutes = milliseconds / 1000 / 60;

console.log( "m => ", minutes );
```

Your approach with new Date( milliseconds ) will give you - as you can see from your result - 30 minutes after the Epoch date, which is January 1, 1970.

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert millisecond to minute as :

```
var milliseconds = 1800000;
var minutes = Math.floor(milliseconds / 60000);
console.log(minutes); // output 30
```